# Hyper TLS cannot be run in Tokio Thread - Does not implement Send

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, hyper

In the [server example provided by the HyperTLS library](https://github.com/rustls/hyper-rustls/blob/master/examples/server.rs), the server provided cannot be run in a `tokio::spawn()` thread without throwing a litany of errors all stemming from the fact that:

`dyn futures_util::Stream<Item = Result<tokio_rustls::server::TlsStream<tokio::net::TcpStream>, std::io::Error>> cannot be sent between threads safely`.

The server definition below is exactly like that found in the example with the exception of the `config` file used to pass in config information.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct HTTPSServer {}

impl HTTPSServer {
    pub async fn start<'a>(config: HTTPSServerConfig<'a>) -> Result<(), HTTPSServerError> {
        // Build TLS configuration.
        let tls_cfg = {
            // Load public certificate.
            let certs = load_certs(&config.cert_path)?;
            // Load private key.
            let key = load_private_key(&config.key_path)?;

            // Do not use client certificate authentication.
            let mut cfg = rustls::ServerConfig::new(rustls::NoClientAuth::new());

            // Select a certificate to use.
            cfg.set_single_cert(certs, key)
                .map_err(|e| error(format!("failed to set single cert: {}", e)))?;
            // Configure ALPN to accept HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1 in that order.
            cfg.set_protocols(&[b"h2".to_vec(), b"http/1.1".to_vec()]);
            sync::Arc::new(cfg)
        };

        let tls_acceptor = TlsAcceptor::from(tls_cfg);

        // Create a TCP listener via tokio.
        let tcp_listener = TcpListener::bind(&config.addr)
            .await
            .map_err(|e| {
                eprintln!("failed to create TCP Listener: {:?}", e);
                e
            })?;

        // Prepare a long-running future stream to accept and serve clients.
        let incoming_tls_stream = stream! {
            loop {
                let (socket, _) = tcp_listener.accept().await?;
                let stream = tls_acceptor.accept(socket)
                    .map_err(|e| {
                        println!("[!] Voluntary server halt due to client-connection error...");
                        // Errors could be handled here, instead of server aborting.
                        // Ok(None)
                        error(format!("TLS Error: {:?}", e))
                    });

                yield stream.await;
            }
        };

        // Setup router
        let service = make_service_fn(|_| async {
            Ok::<_, io::Error>(service_fn(echo))
        });

        // Build server
        let server = Server::builder(HyperAcceptor {
            acceptor: Box::pin(incoming_tls_stream),
        }).serve(service);

        // Run the future, keep going until an error occurs.
        println!("[https-server]: Starting to serve on https://{}.", &config.fqdn);

        server
            .await
            .map_err(|e| {
                eprintln!("[https-server]: error: {:?}", e);
                HTTPSServerError::from(e)
            })

    }
}
```

The following is the `main` method to run the server in a separate thread

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Start the server asynchronously
    let fqdn = "https://localhost:8080";
    let addr = SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(127,0,0,1)), 8080);
    let cert_path = "localhost.crt";
    let key_path = "localhost.key";
    let ca_path = "RootCA.crt";

    let client_config = HTTPSClientConfig {
        fqdn,
        ca_path: Some(ca_path)
    };

    let server_config = HTTPSServerConfig {
        fqdn,
        addr,
        cert_path,
        key_path,
        ca_path,
    };

   // Spawn server in a new thread!
    tokio::spawn(start(server_config)).await.unwrap();

   // A function to kick off a client call to the server.
    client(client_config);
}

async fn start<'a>(server_config: HTTPSServerConfig<'a>) {
    HTTPSServer::start(server_config)
        .await
        .map_err(|e| {
            eprintln!("[https-server]: failed to start server: {:?}", e)
        });
}
```

### The Error

I am not exactly sure how to solve the following error as it doesn't seem trivial to ensure a `dyn` type implements `Send`. Not sure how to solve this.

```rust
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> https/src/main.rs:61:5
    |
61  |     tokio::spawn(start(server_config)).await.unwrap();
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ future returned by `start` is not `Send`
    | 
   ::: /Users/x/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.2.0/src/task/spawn.rs:129:21
    |
129 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ---- required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
    |
    = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `dyn futures_util::Stream<Item = Result<tokio_rustls::server::TlsStream<tokio::net::TcpStream>, std::io::Error>>`
note: future is not `Send` as it awaits another future which is not `Send`
   --> https/src/server.rs:89:9
    |
89  |         server
    |         ^^^^^^ await occurs here on type `hyper::Server<HyperAcceptor<'_>, hyper::service::make::MakeServiceFn<[closure@https/src/server.rs:77:39: 79:10]>>`, which is not `Send`
```

Comment: The error message points you to which variable doesn't implement `Send`: `server` in 89:9.

Comment: Also "doesn't seem trivial to ensure a dyn type implements Send" `dyn MyTrait + Send`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thanks for the reply, I guess my question is, Im not sure how to make the `dyn futures_util::Stream<Item = Result<tokio_rustls::server::TlsStream<tokio::net::TcpStream>, std::io::Error>>` also implement `Send`. Im not sure where to add the `+ Send` trait you mentioned